# How to get only date type without time?

Tags: android, jodatime, android-jodatime

I want to use Date type as Id in Room database, The main reason for this is to be able to check if this date is today. Any suggestion is appreciate

```
@Entity
data class DailyCount(@PrimaryKey
                  var date:DateTime,// JodaTime
                  var summ: MutableLiveData<Double>? = MutableLiveData())
```

I want to make query like this:

```
@Query("update DailyCount set summ = :sum where date = :dailyCount") //update if date is today
fun apdateCash(dailyCount: DateTime, sum: Double)
```

Comment: I posted answer here, it is kind of duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56051963/how-to-use-joda-datetime-date-as-id-in-room-or-how-to-get-date-in-query

Comment: I posted answer here it is kind of duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56051963/how-to-use-joda-datetime-date-as-id-in-room-or-how-to-get-date-in-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use SimpleDateFormatter

```
String jsonDateStr = "03-09-2019 05:45:10"
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

try {
    return fmt.parse(jsonDateStr);
} catch(ParseException pe) {
    return //generate different unique ID like GUID random maybe;    
}
```

Now if you have a date object first, and you need to zero it out, you could do:

```
Date dateObject = Date("03-09-2019 05:45:10") //pseudo for visual
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

try {
     String dateWithZeroedTime = fmt.format(dateObject)
     return fmt.parse(dateWithZeroedTime) //"03-09-2019 00:00:00"   
} catch(ParseException pe) {
    return //generate different unique ID like GUID random maybe;    
}
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: fmt.format returns string. I need to get DateTime type for checking if this date is today

Comment: There are several great tools and wrappers to compare dates like the simple Calendar for example, but since I don't know your full use case, I updated the answer to convert back to the Date object with time zeroed out.

Comment: Updated with more details to help.